# Recreating assets from closed source projects

Tags: copyright, open-source-definition, closed-source, assets

Recently I'm working on a game, where I have created some asset from closed source project.

To be honest I actually re-created assets similar identical to *hill climb*.

Now if I use those or I use those and make my project open-source with those asset, is it illegal/bad-practice/not following community standard/copyright violation ?

Can I get a glimpse of present/future impact?

Answer (score 3):

The assets that you re-created can be protected under multiple different intellectual property protections. Copyright protection is just one of them, but the assets can also be part of a registered [trademark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trademark), [industrial design right](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Industrial_design_right) or ["trade dress"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trade_dress).

If you accidentally re-created the assets from *hill climb*, as in you can prove that you didn't know about their similarity until after you created the assets, then you are not infringing on the copyright of the original assets.

If, on the other hand, you knew about *hill climb* before creating your assets, it is likely that your assets will be seen as derivative works of the original assets and infringing on their copyright (unless you have a license to create derivative works).

In any case, if any of the other intellectual property rights are in force (they usually require an explicit registration), then your assets are definitely infringing on them. For those rights, the creation process does not matter.

Comment: I have played it before, there is lot of evidence of that, *Google Play Store* blah blah.. so technically I don't want to lie, cause I can't actually. So my question is now, if change those color, will there be any problem ?

Comment: @MaifeeUlAsad, that is impossible to tell for a random stranger on the internet. A lot of it depends on how close you imitate the unique recognizable elements of *hill climb* and how aggressive its owners are in protecting their IP rights.

Comment: @MaifeeUlAsad Just changing the colour is not sufficient to avoid copyright infringement. You are not performing infringement if you are using existing artwork as reference images when creating your own art, but you are infringing if you are copying or modifying the original artwork. E.g. if I recreate a photo in my own style that would be fine, but tracing it would already be a grey area.

Comment: Ok, I opened blender , created model from those, and then rendered and I want want use it for 2D and 3D games(mainly), just used those ss as ref image . now ok for me ?

Comment: @MaifeeUlAsad Using a program to open someone else's work, and then clicking "render" in that program to create a new file sounds like you are creating a copy in a new format, or at best a derivative work, of the original work.